# Unable to switch to a new tab in an efficient manner

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping, internet-explorer-11

I've written a script in vba which is able to click on a certain link (`Draw a map`) of a webpage. When the clicking is done, a new tab opens up containing information I would like to grab from. My script can do all these errorlessly. Upon running the script it scrapes the title visible as `Make a Google Map from a GPS file` from the new tab.

My question: is there any alternative way to switch to new tab other than using hardcoded search like `If IE.LocationURL Like "*" & "output_geocoder" Then`?

This is my script:

```
Sub FetchInfo()
    Const url As String = "http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/geocoder/"
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, Html As HTMLDocument, R&
    Dim winShell As New Shell

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate url
        While .Busy = True Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set Html = .document
    End With

    Html.querySelector("input[value$='map']").Click

    For Each IE In winShell.Windows
        If IE.LocationURL Like "*" & "output_geocoder" Then
            IE.Visible = True
            While IE.Busy = True Or IE.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
            Set Html = IE.document
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    Set post = Html.querySelector("h1")
    MsgBox post.innerText
    IE.Quit
End Sub
```

To execute the above script, add this reference to the library:

```
Microsoft Shell Controls And Automation
Microsoft Internet Controls
Microsoft HTML Object Library
```

Btw, there is nothing wrong with the above script. I only wish to know any better way to do the same.

Comment: You are the second person hitting the draw map this weekend. Did you try selenium?

Comment: if your code works fine and you just want a second opinion on efficiency, then [**Code Review**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is a better place for it.  (See: **SO [help/on-topic]**)

Comment: I saw that post and tried to play around with the new tab but all I knew is this method that is why I posted here the same to seek for an alternative approach @QHarr.

Comment: Also, instead of scraping you could just get a map from the [Google Maps API](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/).

Comment: The link used within the above script is just a placeholder. It can be any link containing the feature of opening a new tab. All I wish to know is how to switch to a new tab in any better way @ashleedawg. Btw, thanks for teaching me that day about the usage of Like operator.

Comment: What about switching using the title of new window without a loop? Acceptable? Ah... no!

Comment: Yep, that sounds good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best I have so far with selenium

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim d As WebDriver
    Set d = New ChromeDriver
    Const url = "http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/geocoder/"

    With d
        .Start "Chrome"
        .get url
        .FindElementByCss("input[value$='map']").Click
        .SwitchToNextWindow
        .FindElementByCss("input.gpsv_submit").Click
         MsgBox .Title
        Stop
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

The more fixed with title is:

```
.SwitchToWindowByTitle("GPS Visualizer: Draw a map from a GPS data file").Activate
.FindElementByCss("input.gpsv_submit").Click
```

---

**tl;dr;**

I will need to read up more on how robust `.SwitchToNextWindow` is.

FYI, you can get handles info with:

```
Dim hwnds As List
Set hwnds = driver.Send("GET", "/window_handles")
```

Comment: Yes, it is quicker and cleaner approach. Btw, If you come across any solution using IE related to this issue, feel free to drop here a link. Thanks.

Comment: IE I have always looped. But if I do, I will put it here. There is probably a cmd way to get the info to target without a loop but  I, without evidenced reason, feel it is safer to loop and search for expected text.